# Bootstrap 3.3.6 don't work in my Ruby on Rails 4 project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

It 's been days that i'm trying to settle a problem :I have followed all the steps to use bootstrap 3.3.6 with rails 4 but it don't work, i think maybe the problem is on application.css.sass[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmR5V.png)

it's not colored as it should be so maybe the problem is there. I'm on windows 8

PS: Sorry for my english it's not my langage.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed 2 possible problems:

1. Your import should have file extension, unless your `bootstrap.css` file has no `.css` extension.

   @import 'bootstrap.css'
2. Did you include `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap-sprockets` files in `stylesheets` folder or in your `public` folders?

Comment: 1. I added the extension but it didn't change anything.

Comment: 2. I followed some tutorials and they just install bootstrap at the PC and make imports. I imported them at app\assets\stylesheets\application.css.scss i'm on windows 8

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are adding the @import "bootstrap-sprockets"; and @import "bootstrap"; to your application.js file.

This should be in the application.css.sass

[Look at this image.  This will never work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uQvf.png)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's in application.css.sass.. In application.js i added //= bootstrap-sprockets before //= require_tree .

Comment: Please take a look at the image link above.